# Which ab testing app should I use to measure a mobile app created with HTML and kendoui that will be release in the Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, kendo-ui

In my company we are developing a fitness mobile app using `kendoui`, `HTML`, `jQuery` and `phonegap` and we want to measure the success of the UI design so we want to implement AB testing to try different alternatives in the process. Also, we want to release this app in the `Apple App Store` so our questions are related to.

1. Which app or tool can we use to implement the AB test that fit our software architecture
2. How the App Store manage a app that want to implement AB Testing, they allowed or don't?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only AB testing service compatible with Phonegap is Arise.io.

https://arise.readthedocs.org/en/latest/phonegap.html

Disclamer: I am the CTO of Arise.